# Clean redux state when component unmount cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Guys I want to clear redux state to initial values when component unmount but I got this error

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Here's my code

signup.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies?.resentTimes?.num >= 3) {
      setResentTimes(3);
      setAttempts(3);
    }
    return () => {
      signupCleanup();
      console.log("cleaned up");
    };
  }, []);
```

signup.actions.js

```
export const signupCleanup = () => ({
  type: Types.SIGNUP_CLEANUP,
});
```

signup.reducer.js

```
export default function signup(state = initialState.auth.signup, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHECK_DOMAIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingDomainStart: true,
        checkingDomainError: null,
      };
    case CHECK_DOMAIN_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingDomainStart: false,
        checkingDomainError: action.payload.error,
      };
    case CHECK_DOMAIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingDomainStart: false,
        checkDomainRes: action.payload.res,
      };
    case CHECK_EMAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingEmailStart: true,
        checkingEmailError: null,
      };
    case CHECK_EMAIL_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingEmailStart: false,
        checkingEmailError: action.payload.error,
      };
    case CHECK_EMAIL_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        checkingEmailStart: false,
        checkEmailRes: action.payload.res,
      };
    case VERIFY_CODE:
      return {
        ...state,
        verifyingCodeStart: true,
        verifyingCodeError: null,
      };
    case VERIFY_CODE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        verifyingCodeStart: false,
        verifyingCodeError: action.payload.error,
      }
    case VERIFY_CODE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        verifyingCodeStart: false,
        token: action.payload.token,
      }
    case SET_PASSWORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        settingPasswordStart: true,
        settingPasswordError: null,
      }
    case SET_PASSWORD_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        settingPasswordStart: false,
        settingPasswordError: action.payload.error,
      }
    case SET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        settingPasswordStart: false,
        settingPasswordResponse: action.payload.res,
      }
case SIGNUP_CLEANUP:
  return {
    ...state,
    settingPasswordResponse: null,
    settingPasswordError: null,
    token: null,
    verifyingCodeError: null,
    checkingEmailError: null,
    checkEmailRes: null,
    checkDomainRes: null,
    checkingDomainError: null,
  }
default:
  return state;
```

}
}

Comment: Your component has a local `state` which is dependent on Redux store change. When you are calling the `signupCleanup` function, it ultimately tries to update the local state of your component

Comment: You should use redux dispatch to invoke a redux action which from the code you share doesn't seem to be the case (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Comment: @StavrosAngelis That's happened cause I use signupCleanup action when component unmount which I shouldn't use async actions when component unmout but I don't know where can I reset the redux state to initial values in the component

Comment: From your code "signupCleanup" doesn't appear to be an async function. If I understand correctly from the code you shared you just reset some values in your redux state. If that is the case then there is no need to run  "signupCleanup" as an async function.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis Yeah you're right it's sync but how I can reset redux to initial values when component cleanup

Comment: I think the problem is you don't understand perfectly how to update redux. In this case in your signup.js import useDispatch from react-redux. Now in your component define a new constant const dispatch = useDispatch();Now simply replace signupCleanup(); with dispatch(signupCleanup()); That should update your redux state. If you want to test and see the new values also import useSelector from react-redux. Set a new const settingPasswordError = useSelector((state) =>  state.settingPasswordError);In a new line add a console.log(settingPasswordError).That should output the value with every update.